# Compile From Source For Own Use? (MSVSC++ 2010 Express & CMake 3.1.3)

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2010

I am looking to compile an open source program for personal end use, as opposed to downloading the installer binaries, using CMake 3.1.3 and Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express.

However, after doing research, I am not sure if I can do this without having to make it capable of being redistributed for other users, which I believe would require me to either force in the Redistributable packages (possibly violating ToS?) or buy the commercial version.

How would I configure Visual Studio to build the program from the source files for my own personal use, if possible?

Comment: If it does matter so much to you (and in practice, nobody cares: you won't have a policeman asking your computer for that!), switch to a free software operating system (like most Linux distributions)

Comment: For Microsoft Visual Studio, have a look at the Community Edition: http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs .  *"Any individual developer can use Visual Studio Community to create their own free or paid apps."*  *"Visual Studio Community 2013 includes all the great functionality of Visual Studio Professional 2013, designed and optimized for individual developers, students, open source contributors, and small team"*.

For GCC on Windows I like the TDM-GCC package http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/ .

Comment: @RichardCritter I may try that, though the makers of the source code specifically mentioned using Visual Studio 2010 and CMake. Not sure if it's because of compatibility syntax between the included compilers and their code or not.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I would if more programs and devices that I typically use supported it, I really would. Sadly Windows and iOS "are easier to develop for", so a lot of developers often don't bother with Linux.

Comment: What are the program you are using? I never used Windows (and I am coding since 1974).... what are the programs so specific to Windows that you cannot find something equivalent? I am curious!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Primarily end user entertainment products. Windows and iOS have no shortage of those, but to my knowledge there aren't nearly as many for Linux since it's more commonly used as (and probably better suited for) a development environment.

Comment: Yes, probably Windows is more suited for gaming.